# css counter to number li id attributes

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, scroll, css-counter

Stuck at one interesting problem. I need to assign incremental 'ids' to

elements on the live page on Wordpress wocommerce plugin in order to know what number has each particular product. Here's the example of products output:

```
<ul class="clearfix products"> 
<li id="1" class="post-12345 " data-product-id="12345"> Product 1</li>
<li id="2" class="post-2222 " data-product-id="2222"> Product 2 </li>
<li id="3" class="post-3333" data-product-id="3333"> Product 3</li>
...etc
</ul>
```

Now id's are assigned by jQuery code at footer.php:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var i = 0;
    $(".row ul li").each(function(){
        i++;
        $(this).attr("id", i));

    });
});
</script>
```

All works great but we have an Ajax infinite scroll on the page, so after scrolling down new products appear. And here is the problem: new portion of products has refreshed ids (from 1 to 24). I have tried a lot of different ways to fix this including static php variables, wordpress counter function etc. But observed that the only thing is working for this case is CSS-counter. And such code really numbers products properly (before ):

```
<style>
    .products  {
        counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
    }
    .products li:before {
        counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
        content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
    }
</style>
```

But it list products right at the front-end above the images: 
[Example of products listing by CSS-counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ1T9.jpg)

But how can I put these numbers to the  attribute? In other words, is there something that could put CSS-counter values to each value of jQuery function for example?

Comment: Well, actually nothing works. Even settimeout interval in javascript fails to work after 3-rd iteration of product list uploading. So the only way I think is to put the bloody css-counter to the right id or data-id of <li>. Will write back if success. Any other ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using variable 'i', use the argument 'index' provided in each function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".row ul li").each(function(index, element){
      $(this).attr("id", index));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, Sharmila! But not quite understand where I take function(index, element) arguments? And as I understood, you variant is not related to CSS-counter, right?

Comment: Works like this: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".row ul li").each(function(index){
      $(this).attr("id", index));
  });
}); but only at the first screen. After Ajax refreshing ids go empty

Comment: Hope you need to call this after ajax success callback.. It will start reassign  from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

whoo! I have the solution and it is rather simple if you know javascript well. I dont. But to list the products (whatever) in the

of Wordpress or other site after these li's are uploaded by Ajax from plugin or module which you can't modify by reasons of these plugins must be updated etc.

So, you just need to add the wrap-function to your function which numbers your elements in li like:

```
<script>   

$('.products').on("DOMNodeInserted", function (event) { 
        var id_index = 1;
        $('.product').each(function() {             
            $(this).attr('data-id', id_index);
            id_index++;             
        })          
    });
});
</script>
```

This small pieceof code will add new data-attributes to your list of products